# Laravel public base path when redirecting

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel 5.3, my problem is that if I set any link like this

```
<a href='/'>click here</a>
```

it redirects me to

```
http://localhost
```

But I need it to be like this

```
http://localhost/myprojectname/public
```

It always redirects me to the base path of my server not my base path to the Laravel project. It happenes when im trying to redirect from anything inside the blade or any javascript file, but if I try that in the controller its working fine.

Comment: Are you defining a route for `/`

Comment: yes the main page but i have to write after it my laravelprojectname and / public

Comment: You can define the route of `/` to be at `/myprojectname/public`

Comment: like that i have to define a shared variable with projectname/public value and use it before any link i want to href to

Comment: and thats my problem how can i let laravel know when im using this '/' return me to base my project i mean like  this '/myprojectname/public'

Comment: Any links like `<a href='/'>click here</a>` should instead be `<a href='{{ url('/') }}'>click here</a>`. Laravel will append the right paths if you have your app URL correctly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for base path of the project you need to write following into the app.php in config folder.

```
$APP_FOLDER = "lv-ssm/"; // #LOCAL
//$APP_FOLDER                 = "/"; // #FOR LIVE SERVER

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on') {
    $httpRequest = 'http://';
 } else {
     $httpRequest = 'https://';
 }
    $HTTP_HOST_FULLPATH = $httpRequest . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . 
    $APP_FOLDER;
    $DOCUMENT_ROOT_FULLPATH = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/' . $APP_FOLDER; // #LINUX - #STAGE - #LIVE
```

and this one line in return [] after 'name'=> ''

```
'base_path' => $HTTP_HOST_FULLPATH,
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, in your routes file `rweb.php`

```
Route::get('/', 'Homepagecontroller@index');
```

Define a `Homepagecontroller` to give the home page

```
 public function index(){
     return view('home')
 }
```

Make sure you have `home.blade.php` under `resources/views/`